# JSON object stored in a database table. (How to access)

Tags: laravel-5, yajra-datatable

I have a column name payment_data in my **database table**. data was stored as JSON array using json_encode().

I want to parse the JSON array in my datatable. But I fail.

this is the data that I want to access

***payment_data column***

I updated my data structure to this.

```
Array[2][
  {
    "po_id": 43,
    "full_name": "Dawn Zulita",
    "level": "organization",
    "payment_data": {
      "product_id": "184",
      "product_name": "Grading Org Product",
      "student_name": {
        "0": "Eloise Phillips",
        "1": "Lara vel"
      }
    },
    "date_purchase": "2018-08-10 10:38:08"
  },
  {
    "po_id": 42,
    "full_name": "QWerty You",
    "level": "school",
    "payment_data": {
      "product_id": 185,
      "product_name": "School Owner Manual Payment School Owner Manual Payment",
      "student_name": {
        "0": "Jai Who",
        "1": "Charlie Putt",
        "2": "Kevin Young"
      }
    },
    "date_purchase": "2018-08-09 14:53:35"
  }
]
```

I can now access the payment_data.product_name,

```
{
    data: 'payment_data.product_id'
},
{
    data: 'payment_data.product_name'
},
```

but the problem is I cannot access payment_data.student_name

> error return Undefined index

```
{
    data: 'payment_data.student_name'
},
```

Comment: Have you used `JSON.parse` method in JavaScript?

Comment: @vibs2006 I already did but still, I fail. JSON.parse(data);  Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2

Comment: JSON needs to be in a single line before parsing.

Comment: @vibs2006 I updated my data structure but the problem is I cannot access the payment_data.student_name. but i can access the payment_data.id and the   payment_data.product_name